# How do I configure Tomcat and HAProxy to work with the WebSocket Framework Atmosphere?

Tags: tomcat, websocket, servlet-3.0, haproxy, atmosphere

I have a Java application running on Tomcat7, which uses the [Atmosphere Framework](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere). Atmosphere is a Websocket Framework. I used a sample application from the [Atmosphere Sample Chat](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/tree/master/samples/meteor-chat).
My problem is that I did not get the connectors as well as the proper configuration for my Websocket Atmosphere application running.

The **questions** I have are:

1. How do I have to configure my HAProxy?
2. How do I have to configure my Tomcat server?
3. How do I have to configure Tomcat for APR and for the NIO connector?
4. Do I have to change something in my app (i.e., my web.xml)?
5. How do I have to fix the errors below?

This is my **HAProxy** config:

```
defaults
mode http
log global
option httplog
option  http-server-close
option  dontlognull
option  redispatch
option  contstats
retries 3
backlog 10000
timeout client      25s
timeout connect     5s
timeout server      25s
# timeout tunnel available in ALOHA 5.5 or HAProxy 1.5-dev10 and higher
#   timeout tunnel  3600s
timeout http-keep-alive 1s
timeout http-request        15s
timeout queue        30s
timeout tarpit      60s
default-server inter 3s rise 2 fall 3
option forwardfor


frontend ft_web
  bind *:80 name http
  maxconn 60000

  acl host_testhostdev  hdr(host) -i www.testhost.com

  use_backend apache-8080 if host_testhostdev

  default_backend apache-8080


backend apache-8080
  balance roundrobin

  server websrv1 localhost:8080 maxconn 8000 weight 10 cookie websrv1 check
```

The **web.xml** part for my Atmosphere Servlet:

```
<async-supported>true</async-supported>
<init-param>
   <param-name>org.atmosphere.useNative</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>   

<init-param>
<param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor</param-name>
    <param-value>org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor,org.atmosphere.interceptor.AtmosphereResourceLifecycleInterceptor,org.atmosphere.client.TrackMessageSizeInterceptor</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
   <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.shareableThreadPool</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
   <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.sessionSupport</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
   <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
   <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache</param-value>
</init-param>
```

What I changed in Tomcat **server.xml**

```
!--
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
 -->

<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

These are the **errors** I get:

```
 ERROR cpr.AtmosphereFramework  - If you have more than one Connector enabled, make sure they both use the same protocol, e.g NIO/APR or HTTP for all. If not, org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport will be used and cannot be changed.
```

and

```
 2013-08-02 11:03:11,384 [http-nio-8080-exec-26] ERROR test.ReflectionService  - 
 Service method exception in publishDataCreatedCount in service  ClientNotificationUpdateService
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequest.setAttribute(AtmosphereRequest.java:569)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.executeAsyncWrite(DefaultBroadcaster.java:922)
at org.atmosphere.util.SimpleBroadcaster.queueWriteIO(SimpleBroadcaster.java:192)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.deliverPush(DefaultBroadcaster.java:768)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.push(DefaultBroadcaster.java:666)
at org.atmosphere.util.SimpleBroadcaster.broadcast(SimpleBroadcaster.java:133)
at test.ClientUpdateService.sendToBoard(ClientUpdateService.groovy:46)
at test.ClientNotificationUpdateService.publishDataCreatedCount(ClientNotificationUpdateService.groovy:179)
at test.ReflectionService.callByConvention(ReflectionService.groovy:59)
at test.ClientUpdateService.methodMissing(ClientUpdateService.groovy:65)
at test.NotificationService.create(NotificationService.groovy:206)
at test.HomeController.addAction(HomeController.groovy:402)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

and this one if I access my app with IE8 and IE9:

```
2013-08-08 00:56:19,631 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ERROR cpr.AtmosphereFramework  - AtmosphereFramework exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not supported.
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequest.startAsync(AtmosphereRequest.java:594)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.suspend(Servlet30CometSupport.java:130)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:105)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.doService(Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.java:65)
    at org.atmosphere.container.TomcatWebSocketUtil.doService(TomcatWebSocketUtil.java:87)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.service(Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.java:61)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:1594)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:176)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-08-08 00:56:19,670 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR cpr.AtmosphereFramework  - AtmosphereFramework exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not supported.
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequest.startAsync(AtmosphereRequest.java:594)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.suspend(Servlet30CometSupport.java:130)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:105)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.doService(Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.java:65)
    at org.atmosphere.container.TomcatWebSocketUtil.doService(TomcatWebSocketUtil.java:87)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.service(Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.java:61)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:1594)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:176)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay here is what I would do. Install the APR Connector on your Tomcat server. This will speed up the production environment. Download [APR](http://apr.apache.org/) and follow the install instructions to compile it on your os. You do not need the NIO Connector anymore.

Edit your server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080" 
            protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" 
            URIEncoding="UTF-8" 
            maxThreads="250"
            redirectPort="8443" />
```

Do not use the org.atmosphere.interceptor.AtmosphereResourceLifecycleInterceptor this causes errors for me.

Your HAProxy config is fine. You should also use the atmosphere-runtime-native.jar instead of the atmosphere-runtime.jar.

Your errors might occur because you connect with a browser that does not support websockets to your application which uses websockets.